# New SPN required when renaming server?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, spn

I am in the process of decommissioning a Win 2008 server, that runs an app that uses Kerberos authentication, and has an SPN created for our service account. The replacement server will be renamed to match the old server.

What I am unsure if is if the SPN is associated with the server object in AD. If so, then my concern when I rename the server is that it will break Kerberos until I create a new SPN.

Can I rename the server without having to create a new SPN?